# Reading Xml file path from Windows for application

Tags: c#, xml, windows, winforms, directory

I have my files place in a directory name XMLpackage which is located under the Root of my project
At run time i need to read the file by passing the Path.
By putting my file in debug folder i  was able to read. But in this specific XMLpackage  folder i can not read it.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the file property 'Copy to Output' with value other than 'Do not copy'
To get the file path try,

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "XMLpackage", "file1.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Right click the file in Solution Explorer and click on Properties. Change the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always" as shown in the image.

You can access the file like

```
 string f = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"XMLpackage\TableScripts.xml");
```

[image]